# ROS2 workspace clean

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the equivalent to catkin clean for ROS2 and colcon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330109/ros2-workspace-clean/) by [mikepark93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44418/mikepark93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-08-06

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-08-06**:
There isn't one (yet) see ticket: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/37
You're best off scripting the removal of those directories for now.

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2022-12-15**:
Happy to say, there is one now: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/37#issuecomment-1353287688

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rm -r build install`

---

Originally posted by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) with karma: 274 on 2019-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to *build* and *install*, I would also clean the *log* directory

```
rm -r build install log
```

---

Originally posted by [pfarkas](https://answers.ros.org/users/65764/pfarkas/) with karma: 31 on 2020-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By installing the new colcon-clean extension, you can clean the build, install and log base paths like so:

> sudo apt install python3-colcon-clean
> colcon clean workspace

See the extension's repo readme for more documentation:

https://github.com/colcon/colcon-clean

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2022-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2022-12-19**:
Nice! Thanks for posting.

**Comment by [Remi_Tortue](https://answers.ros.org/users/114193/remi_tortue/) on 2023-06-29**:
What is your configuration?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 ROS2 foxy and it's not available; Unable to locate package python3-colcon-clean.